# Stream Requests Using Spring 5 Reactive Web Client

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-webflux

A TCP Server continuously "Stream in" data. This data needs to be sent to another service to be persisted to database.

Both TCP server and service connected to database are using Spring 5. Because of that i think best way to sent stream data from TCP server is by using `Reactive WebClient` request.

Following is what i have so far.

```
WebClient
  .create()
  .method(HttpMethod.POST)
  .uri("/resource")
  .body("data"), String.class);
```

The problem is how can one continuously send stream data with spring webflux.

## Update

`NMEA` data from a `GPS` device is sent to the the netty TCP server port, which is decrypted and transformed to a java object and sent using http as JSON to a service connect to a database.

Comment: this is rather vague. What kind of data? What's the format? Which API are you using to get that data (provide a code sample, please)?

Comment: Have updated, hope it helps...Any other clarification needed don't hesitate